# ASP / HTML / Javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am working on trying to create a dynamic password reset page where the red X favicons will turn to green check marks when proper conditions are met. Right now the red X stays even when conditions are met. How can I get this to work properly? I have the `script` in the `body` section right now. The password fields being validated are `passR1` and `passR2`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             passR1.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "CallScript(checkPassword())");
        }  


 <script>
         function checkPassword()
         { 

             var ucase = new RegExp("[A-Z]+");
             var lcase = new RegExp("[a-z]+");
             var num = new RegExp("[0-9]+");
             var password1 = document.getElementById("passR1");
             var password2 = document.getElementById("passR2");

             if (password1.val().length >= 8) {
                 $("#8char").removeClass("fa-times");
                 $("#8char").addClass("fa-check");
                 $("#8char").css("color", "#00A41E");
             } else {
                 $("#8char").removeClass("fa-check");
                 $("#8char").addClass("fa fa-times");
                 $("#8char").css("color", "#FF0004");
             }

             if (ucase.test(password1.val())) {
                 $("#ucase").removeClass("fa-times");
                 $("#ucase").addClass("fa fa-check");
                 $("#ucase").css("color", "#00A41E");
             } else {
                 $("#ucase").removeClass("fa-check");
                 $("#ucase").addClass("fa fa-times");
                 $("#ucase").css("color", "#FF0004");
             }

             if (lcase.test(password1.val())) {
                 $("#lcase").removeClass("fa-times");
                 $("#lcase").addClass("fa-check");
                 $("#lcase").css("color", "#00A41E");
             } else {
                 $("#lcase").removeClass("fa-check");
                 $("#lcase").addClass("fa-times");
                 $("#lcase").css("color", "#FF0004");
             }

             if (num.test(password1.val())) {
                 $("#num").removeClass("fa-times");
                 $("#num").addClass("fa fa-check");
                 $("#num").css("color", "#00A41E");
             } else {
                 $("#num").removeClass("fa-check");
                 $("#num").addClass("fa-times");
                 $("#num").css("color", "#FF0004");
             }

             if (password1.val() == password2.val()) {
                 $("#pwmatch").removeClass("fa-times");
                 $("#pwmatch").addClass("fa-check");
                 $("#pwmatch").css("color", "#00A41E");
             } else {
                 $("#pwmatch").removeClass("fa-check");
                 $("#pwmatch").addClass("fa-times");
                 $("#pwmatch").css("color", "#FF0004");
             }
         }

</script>

 <asp:TextBox ID="passR1" runat="server" type="password"  onKeyUp="checkPassword()" ClientMode="Static"  placeholder="New Password" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>

                 </div>
                        <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PassR2" runat="server" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <span id="8char" class="fa fa-times" style="color:#FF0004;"></span> 8 Characters Long<br/>
                            <span id="ucase" class="fa fa-times" style="color:#FF0004;"></span> One Uppercase Letter<br />
                            <span id="SpecChar" class="fa fa-times" style="color:#FF0004;"></span> One Special Character
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <span id="lcase" class="fa fa-times" style="color:#FF0004;"></span> One Lowercase Letter<br/>
                            <span id="num" class="fa fa-times" style="color:#FF0004;"></span> One Number<br />
                            <span id="pwmatch" class="fa fa-times" style="color:#FF0004;"></span> Passwords Match
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: Can you share your html code?

Comment: You should be passing class names to addClass and removeClass, not selectors (no `.`).

Comment: makes no sense to add and remove `fa`, simplify the code `$("#8char").removeClass("fa-times").addClass("fa-check").css("color", "#00A41E");`

Comment: All you guys have had helpful tips, and Thank you I am new to `javascript`. But still no working solution.

Comment: use the debugger in your browser's developer tools to step through the JS code line by line and see what it's doing, and inspect the variable values. Then you can see if the code is taking the paths you expect, and using the values you expect.

Comment: Again, we can't help without a [mre]. Your "HTML" includes ASP.NET code, which is rendered as HTML in the browser, which is actually what we need. You can get that rendered HTML by viewing the page's source.

Comment: One problem here is that you're confusing Vanilla JS and jQuery. `var password1 = document.getElementById("passR1");` means you need `password1.value` to grab the input text. For jQuery's `.val()` you need a jQuery object, which you can get using `var $password1 = $('#passR1");` (note that I have used `$password1` here to indicate that it's a jQuery object, this is just me though, not something you have to do. Also, the console shows the expected `password1 doesn't have a val function` error, which you're supposed to if not fix yourself at least post in the question)

Comment: Here's a rewritten version: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/pme36rzv/

Comment: @ChrisG this is perfect. Many thanks. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept as an answer?

Comment: There's not much point, given that this is a basic mix-up and not really a programming problem likely to be found by future users. That's why I posted as comment. My code is also more about the [dry principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and less about the specific error.